# The website showing Error when opened with WebMatrix

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, webmatrix, sql-server-ce-4

I have developed a website using Asp.Net MVC which uses a SQL CE database in the App_Data. The website when run in Visual Studio, runs fine. But, when i opened it as '*site from folder*' in Microsoft WebMatix. It doesn't show anything. In IE it says "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage" and in chrome it says " Chrome could not connect to localhost:49742".

This happens on the url, where database access is performed. Basic pages work.

I tried opening other website(MvcMusicStore) using '*site from folder*' and it works fine. Why does it happen in the above case when everything is similar. I cannot do the debugging since it is not happening in visual studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably doesn't work because you don't have configured your site with IIS (or another webserver like Cassini).

Probably while in visual studio you have configured your project to use "visual studio development server" with "Auto-assign port". If yes, it's visual studio that starts your web server every time you press F5.

Comment: Mate. It's not that. There is no other server. Besides the other website with the same web.config and database setting work and this doesn't. Don't know how can i figure out whats the reason this is happening

Comment: Besided the Home page of the website loads fine. It is the second page where i am accessing some data, the problem occurs.

Comment: Maybe is the user associated with your app that don't have access to the db. Try checking the read/write auth then. I don't know if it's the same with SQL CE, but with iis 7+ and Sql server usually is APPPOOL\myapppoolname.